# Permissions on webserver

Tags: server-setup, magento-2.2.1, file-permissions, static-content-deploy

My problem came out when we tried to install an extension...then we tried to install another two or three but none of them are working. We cannot have any working extension on our version of Magento (CE 2.2.1) - I am sorry for not being an expert, but I need to paste what a developer said, without understanding too much of it. Is it about permissions on the webserver?How can I get them fixed? **Thank you!**

> But I think when they run the command to generate the static files
>   something is wrong with the permissions or web user that makes the
>   process to fail Because if the extension is working fine in
>   testing/developer mode, there is no reason why it wouldn’t work in
>   production site"
>
> - Do you know how to generate static files in magento? Could you check if anything is failing in that regard?

[image: error message that we've got one of the times we tried to clear the cache]

Comment: use  **sudo chmod -R 777 pub/media pub/static generated var** from magento root via SSH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get them fixed?

To fix them you simply need to ssh onto the server and confirm/set the correct user and group via `chown user:group directory/` and then if the access permissions are incorrect you can fix via `chmod ### directory/` where ### is the read/write permission you wish to set it to, eg 777 for full read/write.

If you don't have ssh access to your server then your server provider will need to do this for you.

Comment: in this case `chown user:www-data`  will solve problem

Comment: @DanCarlyon The first command chown user:group doesnt work, I also replaced "user" with the user that we use, but I get 
"bash: chown: command not found"

Comment: Sorry i missed the end of it should be `chown user:group directory/` if it still says command not found that could be a big problem, i'd need to know the os and version

Comment: @DanCarlyon thanks a lot for your time!I actually solved then contacting the hosting company and they did it for me...I'm gonna use your suggestion next time that I have the same problem - hopefully never! Have a nice one!

Comment: Glad i could help and thankyou for up voting my answer :)